# Asus P5N-D Motherboard / NVIDIA nForce 750i SLI Southbridge: mix RAID1 and non-RAID?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, nvidia-nforce

I have an Asus P5N-D motherboard which includes the NVIDIA nForce 750i SLI chipset.  The motherboard has 4 Serial ATA 3Gb/s slots and the chipset supports RAID 0, RAID 0+1, RAID 5, and JBOD.  I currently have a RAID 1 setup.  However, I'd like to add another hard drive (an SSD) which will become my primary drive while the RAID 1 drive becomes my data drive.  Is this configuration typically supported?

Answer (score 1):

So far as I know this should be fine, on most raid controllers you should be able to set whether a disk is handled by the raid controller or the BIOS. Most probably this setting is in the bios, however check in both places.